# Horizontal scrolling a table

Tags: css, html

On my webpage [here](http://ziga-lausegger.com/strani/index.php) I currently have a table which has too many columns and exceeds it's holder in x direction. In CSS I have it set up so that horizontal slider is shown and people can use it to navigate left/right across the table. This is achieved using `overflow-x: auto;` in CSS.

But slider looks outdated and Firefox doesn't support slider altering so far. That's why I decided that I want to disable the slider by altering overflow like this `overflow-x: hidden;`. This hid the slider away, but now I can't scroll my table left/right.

Are there any easy solutions that I can use to scroll the table **left/right** while my scrollbar remains hidden? Usage of **mouse wheel** or **hold & pull** actions would be completely fine.

Comment: pushing shift key and mouse wheel should work for you

Comment: This only works if scrollbar isn't hidden. When I hide it it doesn't work anymore. Also it isn't convenient to hold SHIFT key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: It is not. That question only focuses on **vertical mouse wheel scrolling**. This one is **horizontal** and I am not focusing only on mouse wheel - I am also interested in hold and pull scrolling...

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "hold and pull scrolling"?

Comment: To press left mouse button and move the mouse left/right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for horizontal as if it would have visible scrollbar

***Update**: Added a dragscroll script*

*Src: [http://qnimate.com/javascript-scroll-by-dragging/](http://qnimate.com/javascript-scroll-by-dragging/_)*

```css
#container1{
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 25px;   /* push scrollbar out of sight */
    margin-top: 15px;
    cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/asvd/dragscroll/master/dragscroll.js"></script>

<div id="container1"><div class="dragscroll" id="container2">
    hello 1
    hello 2
    hello 3
    hello 4
    hello 5
    hello 6
    hello 7
</div><div>
```